# Selection of events from the database by timestamp

Tags: sqlite

I have a Sqlite3 database, with a `reports` table, the table has an `date INTEGER`  field, it stores Unix timestamps, I want to make two choices:

```
CREATE TABLE reports (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user_id, report, date INTEGER);
SELECT * FROM reports;
1|123456|report|1546965098
```

1.All entries for the previous month;

2.All entries from the first day of this month to today.

I tried it, but it did not work out.

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE datetime(date, 'unixepoch') >= date('now', '-1 month);
```

I understand that something is lacking, but unfortunately, not enough knowledge of sql.
Tell me, please, how to make such records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 1st day of the previous month, you need this:

```
date('now','start of month','-1 month')
```

so you want dates starting from the above date up to and not including the 1st day of the current month, which is:

```
date('now','start of month')
```

So your statement to get the rows of the previous month can be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM reports 
WHERE 
  datetime(date, 'unixepoch') >= date('now','start of month','-1 month')
  AND 
  datetime(date, 'unixepoch') < date('now','start of month');
```

The 2nd statement is simpler:

```
SELECT * 
FROM reports 
WHERE 
  datetime(date, 'unixepoch')
  BETWEEN 
  datetime('now', 'start of month') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!